# newcommand for math mode only

Tags: math-mode, macros, overleaf, preamble

My preamble contains the following definition

```
\newcommand*  {\pdiffat}[3] {\left(\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}\right)_{#3}}
```

which is meant to be used in math mode only. However, overleaf complains that `\left` must only be used in math mode and hence colors this line and all subsequent lines in pink/red.

Is there a (ideally simple) way to avoid this? I.e. such that the macro with the same functionality still works, but overleaf is happy?

Comment: I do not use overlead, but is wrapping the definition in `\ensuremath{...}` acceptable?

Comment: Remove the spaces between the * and the command name, then overleaf will behave again.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Before egreg gets to you :) [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830)

Comment: @AlanMunn My comment was an "in case of fire, break glass" kind of reply, but your admonition is well stated.

Comment: The only way is to ask Overleaf to avoid that silly behavior for macro definitions in the document preamble.

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf support speaking. The solution by @UlrikeFischer should work. Still, I'll raise this with our engineers to see whether we can teach this to the parser.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes If you make your suggestion into an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the spaces between the \newcommand*  and the command name, they seem to confuse the overleaf parser. This here works fine for me:

```
 \newcommand*{\pdiffat}[3]{\left(\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}\right)_{#3}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite the many reasons not to do it this way, and Alan's comment provides a link about not using `\ensuremath`, I nonetheless suggested placing an `\ensuremath` around the code, as in

```
\newcommand*{\pdiffat}[3]{\ensuremath{\left(\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}\right)_{#3}}}
```

In this manner, the command will function when invoked in either text or math modes.

I did not suggest this as a general approach to macro making, but only as a possible remedy for the particular overleaf problem the OP was experiencing. (I have no knowledge of overleaf, myself)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\pdiffat}[3]{\ensuremath{\left(\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}\right)_{#3}}}

\pdiffat{a}{b}{c} vs. $\pdiffat{a}{b}{c}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find the statements about `\ensuremath` a bit over the top. For pretty much anything you can construct scenarios where this something does not give the optimal result.